# using TranslateService inside a normal function (without class/constructor)

Tags: angular

Is there away to do an import import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core'; and use it without constructors/class such as the following function:

```
export function myname(){
   translate = new TranslateService();
   return translate.instance('title') + '. Daniels';
   }
```

Comment: don't think so. You inject a service... Services are singletons within the scope of an injector... in constructor, we get an instance of the injected service;

Comment: oh thanks @AkberIqbal. Guessed as much but wanted to make sure since the codebase wasn't mine to move around.