# How to use NGX Translate in static classes or independent custom functions written in the application?

Tags: ngx-translate

Using dependency injection like below, I know I can call the translation service. But I have few scenarios where I don't intend to have a constructor-

```
constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService
  ) { }
```

Can anyone please suggest if there is a way where I can create a static class and use it like any other normal utility class function? Or if I could somehow get the global reference to translation service without injecting the dependency.

Comment: Does [importing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56649754) help? See also: [Don't think so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417060/using-translateservice-inside-a-normal-function-without-class-constructor#comment95644101_54417060).

Comment: @greybeard As per the documentation, the only way to work with TranslationService is 1) First to import the service. 2) Then, to inject the dependency in the constructor. My question is for static class, how do I achieve the translation functionality without having dependency injection.

Comment: for normally working app u can't do it. i have expirience with using translateService with inject (custom function in app). after doing this classes will not remove from user memory after descroy component who use this class. if user will get a lot of classes with injected translateService - all will stay in user ram and your service will laggy

Comment: try to use different, but good way (translate keys into html files). static class will only have some keys and params for it